# What is the difference between the "Authenticated Users" and "Users" security groups?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs

I'm trying to figure it out why there is a difference in the checkboxes in permissions on "Users" and "Authenticated Users" in created "TestFolder". Both settings - marked in red and orange apply to "this folder, subfolders and files" so are equal for both. So what and why is difference in yellow permissions?

I'm only talking about and testing local permission, not network sharing.

Looking at these:

```
Create files / write data
Create folders / append data
...
```

It's confusing whether it is or is NOT possible to create/write/append.

I'm logged in as a local user on this VM, so in theory I'm in the built-in "Users" group. Looking at the left yellow square (Users Win7-CL1\Users) it should NOT be possible for me to create/write etc. On the other hand after successfully logging on, a user is treated by the system as an "Authenticated User", so this should fall into the right yellow square. So it should be possible for him (me) to create/write etc.

When I tested on the VM, I was able to create/write etc, so it looks like "Authenticated Users" take precedence over "Users." Am I correct?

If so then after successfully logging in, each user is an "Authenticated User," so never fall into the "Users" group.

When is one treated as a "user"?

[image]

Comment: Could you please use the EDIT button to add formatting and punctuation and to correct spelling so this question is easier to understand?

Answer (score 2):

You are in multiple groups at once. Your token has the `BUILTIN\Users` SID, *and* it has the `Authenticated Users` SID, *and* it has the `Everyone` SID, and it has a few other SIDs as well. **All** of those groups are used when checking ACLs.

NTFS ACLs, unlike POSIX ACLs, are not exclusive: the **sum** of all matching access entries applies to you. For example, if the file has `Users:(R)` and `Authenticated Users:(W)` granted to it, then you have Read *and* Write access. This means that one group never *needs* to take precedence over another.

Instead, the ACEs are sorted such that "Deny" entries take precedence over "Allow" entries. If at least one entry explicitly denies some permission, it will be denied even if another entry tries to allow it.

Comment: Yes in fact this user was both in "Users" group and "Administrators" group at same time. So I deleted "Users" so only I'm just member of Administrators group. After log out and logon again I created new folder but in permissions tab still Users and Auth...users have same chackboxes like in 1st post... :(

Comment: @mattin - The contents of your question does not reflect that fact

Comment: @Ramhound - the situation is not static, things changes so thats why I deleted "Users" group and only threre is Administrators. So now afted deletion for new created folder in permission tab there is no change and still entry for users exists (aor administrators, authenticated users too) So I see some unconsequence here.

Comment: I don't understand your issue with "users having same checkboxes". Of course they do – the checkboxes show configured permissions, not effective permissions.